# Is it possible to use the device simulator without the Dev Tools opened?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Is it possible to use the device simulator without the Dev Tools opened?

Usually, we do demos of our mobile-friendly and responsive application using the DevTools device simulator. By default, you need to open the DevTool panel for the Device simulator.

**But is it possible to have the Device Simulator without the DevTools?**

[image: DevTools and Device Simulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamefully to me (and maybe counter intuitively), seems to be possible by just closing the DevTools (with the cross or shortcut) with the device simulator enabled.

[image: Close DevTools with Device Simulator]

I do not know why I did not try that first, before asking.

Comment: I've never seen this behavior before. There must be some setting you have enabled?

Comment: Yes, it's not the default behavior. Can't do it on my system.

Comment: Until you refresh.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge you cannot have the device toolbar open without developer tools. You can however dock the developer tools pane to a seperate window in the settings, so you can do testing without it interfering.